# serverless: command not found in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to set up the AWS Serverless framework in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed Node.js and have also installed Serverless using the following command: `npm install -g serverless` in the terminal. 
But when I try to run `serverless` it returns an error saying `serverless: command not found`. Below is a screenshot for reference:

[image: Command not found error]

Comment: What was the output of your serverless install? It should give you a path where it was installed, such as `~/npm-global/lib/node-modules` or something like to tell you where it is installed.

Answer (score 78):

Try running,

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

and then,

```
npm i -g serverless
```

Comment: Efffffffing finally. This also solved my issue on Mac OS using iTerm 2 and zsh

Comment: That did the trick on macOS, nothing about this in the serverless doco that I could find

Comment: @Kong it wasnt a serverless issue, its an npm configuration issue

Comment: Thanks for this @Manoj bro!
Also if you get a permission issue run  `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib`

Comment: The first command messes with `nvm`, don't use it if you use `nvm`.

Answer (score 13):

If the above options are not working (due to insufficient access or sudo access), following one will definitely work as it's saving the serverless into your local.

```
npm install serverless --save-dev
node ./node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless deploy
```

Reference link - https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/services/

Answer (score 12):

Was getting the same error *serverless: command not found* but instead of NPM was using YARN. To fix it had to execute (or better add to your ~/.bash_profile):

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)"
```

then, if not already installed:

```
yarn global add serverless
```

Comment: This one helps a lot.

Comment: haha I just didn't have the serverless installed globally. :D

Answer (score 9):

my recomendation here is to allways install the serverless framework as a dev dependency (`npm install serverless --save-dev`) specially if you're working in a team where each member can have its own version of the framework. After that, you can call the framework using npm scripts. For example, you can create a new entry in the scripts section like this: `"deploy" : "serverless deploy"` and call it using `npm run deploy`.

Comment: to extend this good answer, different ways to invoke serverless CLI are described in official docs https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/services#invoking-serverless-locally

Answer (score 4):

Try with the following order

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local

sudo npm i -g serverless

sudo /usr/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/tabtab/src/cli.js install --name serverless --auto
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, following this [post](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4889), is to try `npx serverless ...`